# Why doesn't BokehJS show in a rendered Jupyter/IPython notebook on GitHub?

Tags: github, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
N = 4000
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
radii = np.random.random(size=N) * 1.5
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, 150) for r, g in zip(np.floor(50+2*x), np.floor(30+2*y))]
output_notebook()
# Loading BokehJS ...
p = figure()
p.circle(x, y, radius=radii, fill_color=colors, fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)
show(p)
```

However, it does not show any plot or graphics; it simply is stuck on "Loading BokehJS".

In principle, this should work with nbviewer, as rendered notebooks are stripped of all Javascript on GitHub (I think?). In my experience however, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub scrubs all JavaScript from all Jupyter notebooks before rendering them (presumably for security reasons). Bokeh requires JavaScript code from the client library BokehJS in order to render or do anything at all. Given this, I would not expect Bokeh plots in Jupyter notebooks to *ever* work on GitHub, unfortunately.

I would very much like for it to be workable, but it is entirely outside our control. I have reached out to GitHub asking for an option to disable rendering entirely for notebooks in a repo, on the reasoning that "not rendering at all" is preferable to "rendering but looking broken" but have not heard back from them.

Note that nbviewer does *not* strip JavaScript, which is why all the notebooks at the [Bokeh nbviewer.org gallery](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/index.ipynb) show up just fine.

Comment: > "Note that nbviewer does not strip JavaScript, which is why all the notebooks at the Bokeh nbviewer.org gallery show up just fine."

I've noticed this. When I put my notebooks on github into nbviewer, they still don't show up. How do you use nbviewer in order for notebook to show up?

Comment: There may be an issue with `0.12.1` and statically rendered notebooks. This is under active investigation, and will be resolved in `0.12.2`. There's and issue and WIP PR on GitHub if you'd like to follow. For now I'd suggest using `0.12`.

Comment: Link to the Issue? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help!